# work stealing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, queue, work-stealing

I am reading an article about Concurrency Runtime, and there is algorithm named `work stealing` in this article. but I have no idea what this algorithm is! so I want a little explanation or some good link that could help me to make a presentation about this algorithm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are any of these helpful?

[Work-Stealing in .NET 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2009/06/26/work-stealing-in-net-4-0.aspx)

[Scheduling Multithreaded Computations by Work Stealing](http://supertech.csail.mit.edu/papers/steal.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, the first like was good enough:) but second link is so long:D

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

I recently read that paper, which describes a Java Fork / Join framework with Work Stealing Algroithms found [here](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/fj.pdf)

Taken from that paper, we start with this:

```
Result solve(Problem problem) {
    if (problem is small)
       directly solve problem
    else {
       split problem into independent parts
       fork new subtasks to solve each part
       join all subtasks
       compose result from subresults
    }
}
```

Those forked subtasks (line 2 in the else block) can recursively create more subtasks themself and thus fill up the working queues of the parallely working threads. If one thread finished and has nothing more to do, he can "steal" the work from the queue of another thread.

So much for short, for all the details I would suggest looking into the paper.

Comment: very informative article. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty nice and easy-to-understand explanation of the Work Stealing algorithm you can find in the following Channel9 video:  ["Parallel Extensions: Inside the Task Parallel Going Deep" Duffy, Huseyin Yildiz, Daan Leijen, Stephen Toub](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Joe-Duffy-Huseyin-Yildiz-Daan-Leijen-Stephen-Toub-Parallel-Extensions-Inside-the-Task-Parallel), see  from `00:44:00` (by [Daan Leijen](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/daan/))

Comment: very informative video. thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

you could have a look at Intel TBB algorithm for task scheduler, it is using Work Stealing pattern. See https://software.intel.com/fr-fr/node/468190