# Understanding the work stealing algorithm

Tags: java-threads, work-stealing

I have read a lot on this algorithem. When explaining this algorithem , the words :
[work stealing algorithm [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081382/work-stealing-algorithm)

> Those forked subtasks can recursively
>   create more subtasks themself and thus fill up the working queues of
>   the parallely working threads. If one thread finished and has nothing
>   more to do, he can "steal" the work from the queue of another thread.

I understand that this algorithem is new and does not exists in Executors.newCachedThreadPool / Executors.newFixedThreadPool

I would like to see that one thread handles only work from it's queue.
I created a small program that creates threads recursively. see below.
How can I see that it doesn't use the work stealing algorithem ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] myArray = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).toArray();

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        CustomCallable customCallable = new CustomCallable(myArray, executorService);
        customCallable.call();
        executorService.shutdownNow();
}
public class CustomCallable implements Callable<Integer> {
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 2;
    private int[] array;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public CustomCallable(int[] array, ExecutorService executorService) {
        this.array = array;
        this.executorService = executorService;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        int sum = 0;
        log.debug(" start [{}] ", Arrays.toString(array) );
        if (array.length > THRESHOLD) {
            List<Callable<Integer>> dividedTasks = createSubtasks(array, executorService);
            sum = executorService.invokeAll(dividedTasks).stream()
                    .mapToInt(feature -> {
                        try {
                            return feature.get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return 0;
                    })
                    .sum();
       } else {
            sum = processing(array);
        }
        log.debug(" sum[{}]={} ", Arrays.toString(array) ,sum);
        return sum;
    }

    private List<Callable<Integer>> createSubtasks(int[] array, ExecutorService executorService) {
        int[] arr1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, array.length / 2);
        int[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, array.length / 2, array.length);
        List<Callable<Integer>> dividedTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        dividedTasks.add(new CustomCallable(arr1, executorService));
        dividedTasks.add(new CustomCallable(arr2, executorService));
        return dividedTasks;
    }

    private Integer processing(int[] array) {
        int result = Arrays.stream(array)
                .sum();
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the output :

```
[main] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]  
[pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]  
**[pool-2-thread-3] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[1, 2]]**  
[pool-2-thread-2] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]  
[pool-2-thread-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[3, 4, 5]]  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[6, 7]]  
**[pool-2-thread-3] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[1, 2]]=3**  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[6, 7]]=13  
**[pool-2-thread-3] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[8, 9, 10]]**  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[3]]  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[3]]=3  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[4, 5]]  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[4, 5]]=9  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[8]]  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[8]]=8  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[9, 10]]  
[pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[9, 10]]=19  
**[pool-2-thread-3] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[8, 9, 10]]=27**  
[pool-2-thread-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[3, 4, 5]]=12  
[pool-2-thread-2] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]=40  
[pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]=15  
[main] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]=55
```

As you can see :

main triggered thread-2 and thread-1

thread-1 triggered **thread-3(calculating [1,2])** and thread-4

thread-2 triggered thread-5 and **thread-3(calculating [1,2] after finishing calculating[8,9,10])**
As I understand thread-3 handles work from thread-1 and thread-2.
Looks like thread-3 *work steal*
If I change it to

```
 ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
```

which supports workstealing algorithem, what do I see differently ?

```
[main] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[1, 2]]  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[1, 2]]=3  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[3, 4, 5]]  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[6, 7]]  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[6, 7]]=13  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[8, 9, 10]]  
**[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[3]]**  
**[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[3]]=3**  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[4, 5]]  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[4, 5]]=9  
**[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[8]]**  
**[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[8]]=8**  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  start [[9, 10]]  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-4] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[9, 10]]=19  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[3, 4, 5]]=12  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[8, 9, 10]]=27  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]=15  
[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]=40  
[main] DEBUG com.example.CustomCallable -  sum[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]=55
```

As you can see we have 5 workers and worker-4 handles work triggered by worker-3 as well as worker-1. In what way this is different from the previous execution ?

You can download the code from [github](https://github.com/idaamit/trigger-threads-examples/tree/master/recursive-opening-threads)